# ldapsearch silently fails to connect to an AD LDAPS due to non-authentication of the AD LDAPS server

Tags: openldap

I have a certificate chain that is coming from a big company AD LDAP, i can check as follows :

```
$ openssl rehash tmp_cert_dir/ 
$ echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 10.188.1.101:636 2</dev/null \ 
       | openssl verify -CApath  tmp_cert_dir/ 
stdin: OK
$
```

So i suppose the 2 certificates in the directory `tmp_cert_dir` are sufficient to authentifiate the LDAP server.

But when using `ldapsearch` commando, i cannot use the `LDAPTLS_CACERTDIR` environement variable.

```
$ LDAPTLS_CACERTDIR=/root/tmp_cert_dir ldapsearch -x -W -D mydomain\\mylogin -H ldaps://10.188.1.101 $SECRET_SEARCH
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
$
```

Indeed it answers when using the `LDAPTLS_REQCERT` to disable certificate authentication, then the research successfully answers.

```
$ LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never ldapsearch -x -W -D mydomain\\mylogin -H ldaps://10.188.1.101 $SECRET_SEARCH
Enter LDAP Password: 
(<correct answer here>)
```

In previous researchs on the Internet, i found an aboundance of persons suggesting to abanadon server authentication, but i would like to use this authentication.

How can i get `ldapsearch` to output some errors messages instead of silently failing to connect?  How can i authenticate my LDAP server?